# Evaluating Fourier transform in mathematica

Tags: fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

I am trying to evaluate the expression

```
FourierTransform[[m (a^2 - t^2 - I g t)]^-1, t, ω]
```

in Mathematica. It gives me the error message that "Syntax: "[m(a^2-t^2-I g t)]" is incomplete; more input is needed."

Please help. I am not an expert. In the expression above m, a, g are positive real numbers.

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. Did you mean `FourierTransform[m (a^2-t^2-I g t)^-1,t,\[Omega]]` ?  When posting code here, `InputForm` should be used.  Do not use `[ ]` for grouping terms. Use `(  )` instead.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. I just tried that. It is taking too much time now. It does have a simple closed-form solution which I know.

Comment: Are you sure the input you show is the correct one? is it from a book? may be you can post screen shot.

Comment: I am trying to find the Fourier transform of $G(\omega)=[m(\omega_0^2-\omega^2-i\gamma\omega)]^{-1}$ which is the Fourier transform of the Green function $G(t)$ of the damped harmonic oscillator. In the input code, I have written $t$ for $\omega$, and renamed other variables.

Comment: **Fourier transform of G(ω)** it looks to me you want to find the InverseFourierTransform there and not the FourierTransform?  You want to go from $\omega$ to $t$, right?

Comment: Please correct the simple mistake in the code posted in your question. If `m`, `a`, `g` are specific numeric value, the transform calculates fast e.g. `With[{m = 1, a = 2, g = 10}, FourierTransform[m (a^2 - t^2 - I g t)^-1, t, \[Omega]]]` Not sure about why symbolic coefficients lead to such slow-down, `Assumptions -> {a > 0, g > 0, m>0}` doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @Nasser Yes. Indeed. But that too is taking an unusually long time. Something seems wrong.

Comment: @xzczd Yes, with specified values of the parameters, InverseFourierTransform does give the correct result but I think Mathematica is capable of giving the exact analytic result without putting values of the parameters.

Comment: **Do you have any idea why it fails to find the IFT without specific values of m, g and w0?** Sorry, I do not know without looking more into it. May be someone else will be able to figure out why and if it is even possible. I also tried assumption but that did not help.

Comment: Using `Maple 2023` with code: `inttrans:-fourier(1/(a^2 - t^2 - g*t*I), t, w)` translated to Wolfram Language we have: `1/Sqrt[4 a^2 - 
  g^2]\[Pi] (-I E^(-(1/2) I (-I g + Sqrt[(2 a - g) (2 a + g)]) w)
     Sign[Im[Sqrt[4 a^2 - g^2]] - Re[g]] - 
   I E^(1/2 I (I g + Sqrt[(2 a - g) (2 a + g)]) w)
     Sign[Im[Sqrt[4 a^2 - g^2]] + Re[g]] - 
   2 E^(-((g w)/2)) Sin[1/2 Sqrt[4 a^2 - g^2] w] + 
   4 E^(-((g w)/2)) Sin[1/2 Sqrt[4 a^2 - g^2] w] UnitStep[w])`

Comment: In Maple 2023 I obtain $$\frac{4 \sin\! \left(\frac{\omega  \sqrt{4 a^{2}-g^{2}}}{2}\right) {\mathrm e}^{-\frac{g \omega}{2}} \mathrm{Heaviside}\! \left(\omega \right) \pi}{\sqrt{4 a^{2}-g^{2}}} $$ through `inttrans:-fourier(1/(a^2 - t^2 - g*t*I), t, omega) assuming g>0 ,a>0;` and simplification. The result is confirmed by `invfourier`.

Answer (score 2):

The square in the denominator has roots

```
Solve[a^2 - t^2 - I g t == 0, t]

{{t -> 1/2 (-I g - Sqrt[4 a^2 - g^2])}, 
 {t -> 1/2 (-I g + Sqrt[4 a^2 - g^2])}}
```

So do the FourierTransform with a genral square in the denominator

```
    Assuming[g > 0 && a > g/2,  
Simplify@(FourierTransform[(m (u - t) (v - t))^-1, t, \[Omega]] /.
{u -> 1/2 (-I g - Sqrt[4 a^2 - g^2]),  
v -> 1/2 (-I g + Sqrt[4 a^2 - g^2])})]

    -((I E^(1/ 2 (g - I Sqrt[4 a^2 - g^2]) \[Omega])* 
(-1 + E^(I Sqrt[4 a^2 - g^2] \[Omega])) Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]*  
HeavisideTheta[-\[Omega]])/(Sqrt[4 a^2 - g^2] m))
```

Comment: Simpler: ``F = Integrate`ComplexApart[(a^2 - t^2 - I g t)^-1, 
  t]; FourierTransform[F/m, t, \[Omega]]`` .